# Data from objects created from FileReader in a web app then passed to Google Apps Script client-side return empty, undefined, null

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, filereader, multifile-uploader, multi-upload

My web app has a few file input elements where the user can upload any number of files of different types. I'm trying to store all data first in an array the same size of the number of input elements, where each item in the said array contains an array of data (filename, blob, mimetype) from each uploaded file.

The user can choose to upload or not, but if they don't, I still need to save some reference for that row with an empty upload by getting its data attribute (header).

The data appears in the browser console, but it returns undefined/empty/null when accessed from the client side of Google Apps Script. I'm not very familiar with the FileReader.

On the server side, I want to create a file in Google Drive from each blob and finally store the URL in Sheets.

Thanks in advance!

```
function saveFormData(){

  var fileInputs = document.querySelectorAll('tr.result-row td > input.upload');
  var firstUploadIndex = fileInputs[0].parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('data-index');

  //Loop through all upload rows
  var uploads = []; //will be array of arrays of multi-uploaded files; each item inside belongs to 1 column in db
  Array.from(fileInputs).forEach(input => {

    var files = input.files; //object file list

    if(files.length < 1){ //if there's no file in the upload input
      var header = input.getAttribute('data-uploadtype'); //save the header name as reference
      var fileData = [header, '', '', '']; 
      uploads.push(fileData);
    } else { //if there's a file/s in the upload input
      var innerUploads = []; //array of data for each file
      //Loop through all these files
      for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        
        var currentFile = files[i]; 

        if(!currentFile) return; //if no current file, just in case
        const fr = new FileReader();

        fr.onload = (e) => {
          var data = e.target.result.split(','); //split current file
          var fileData = { binary: data[1], mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], filename: currentFile.name };
          innerUploads.push(fileData);
        }
        fr.readAsDataURL(currentFile);
      } //CLOSES FOR LOOP
      uploads.push(innerUploads);

    } //CLOSES IF
  
  }); //CLOSES FOR EACH LOOP

  google.script.run.saveToDrive(uploads);

} //CLOSES FUNCTION
```

This is what the upload interface looks like.
[image: upload elements inside table cells]

Comment: I think that the reason for your current issue is due to that FileReader is run with the asynchronous process. But, in your script, your `uploads` includes an array like `var fileData = [header, '', '', '']` and an object like `var fileData = { binary: data[1], mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], filename: currentFile.name }`. So, I'm worried that if `google.script.run.saveToDrive(uploads);` is run with `uploads`, another issue might occur. So, in your question, I think that it is required to show the script of `saveToDrive`. How about this?

Comment: My saveToDrive just has console.log for the data I'm trying to get from the client side. But I'm planning to just loop through the arrays, get the blob, create file in Drive, get the url, and save to specific ranges in Sheets.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, in this case, how will you do the value like `[header, '', '', '']`? I think that in your script, it seems that you are trying to retrieve an array including `[header, '', '', '']` and `{ binary: data[1], mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], filename: currentFile.name }`. So, I cannot still understand the relationship between this value and your reply. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected result?

Comment: I would like to confirm your question. For example, in your this question, you want to retrieve values from `fileInputs`, and even when the values of `[header, '', '', '']` and `{ binary: data[1], mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], filename: currentFile.name }` are included in `uploads`, tht is no problem, and also, your this question is different from your final goal of `But I'm planning to just loop through the arrays, get the blob, create file in Drive, get the url, and save to specific ranges in Sheets.`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I would like to think of a solution by correctly understanding your question. I deeply apologize that I try to correctly understand your question.

Comment: The only problem I'm asking a solution for is to return the final array (uploads) to the client side so I can loop through it and access each item, or the items inside each item. Maybe it's the asynchronous process that's should be handled?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. In this case, the values of `uploads` are created. From your reply, here, I didn't propose the script of `saveToDrive`. Please be careful about this. If my answer was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from `fileInputs` and create an array of `uploads` including the values like `[header, '', '', '']` and `{ binary: data[1], mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], filename: currentFile.name }`.

When I saw your script, I thought that the reason for your current issue is due to that FileReader is run with the asynchronous process. This has already been mentioned in my 1st comment.

When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please modify your Javascript as follows.

```js
function getFiles(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = e => {
      const data = e.target.result.split(",");
      const obj = { binary: data[1], mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], fileName: file.name };
      resolve(obj);
    }
    if (file) {
      fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
      reject("No file");
    }
  });
}

async function saveFormData() {
  var fileInputs = document.querySelectorAll('tr.result-row td > input.upload');
  // var firstUploadIndex = fileInputs[0].parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('data-index'); // This is not used in your showing script.
  var uploads = [];
  var ar = Array.from(fileInputs);
  for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    var files = ar[i].files;
    if (files.length == 0) {
      var header = ar[i].getAttribute('data-uploadtype'); //save the header name as reference
      var fileData = [header, '', '', ''];
      uploads.push(fileData);
    } else {
      for (var j = 0; j < ar[i].files.length; j++) {
        var res = await getFiles(ar[i].files[j]).catch(err => console.log(err));
        uploads.push(res);
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(uploads); // You can confirm the value in the log.

  google.script.run.saveToDrive(uploads);
}
```

- Unfortunately, I cannot know your actual HTML. So, I modified your script by guessing your HTML. If an error occurs, please provide the HTML. By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: This looks promising! I'll try to run it later and update you. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Jed Santos Thank you for replying. When I tested this, no error occurs. But, when you test it, if this script was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike. The script is good! I just did a tiny modification so I can create an inner array in the else part of saveFormData. This way, the res goes to that inner array first, then this inner array finally goes into the uploads array. Thank you so much! Till next time.

Comment: @Jed Santos Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply and the current situation, I cannot understand whether your question was resolved. Can I ask you whether your question was resolved? If my answer was not useful, I have to apologize.

Comment: Your updated code solved my problem. I have marked your answer as the right one. Thanks!